# Python packages still marked as not installed in Intellij even after "installed successfully" mesage

Tags: python, intellij-idea

In a python project inside Intellij

[image]

and using an `sdk` that includes `ipython`:

[image]
we see that `IPython` is not found:

[image]

Well OK (it *is* available on command line)

[image]

But in any case let's go ahead and install it:

[image]

That "apparently" succeeds .. ?

[image]

But wait ..  It still gives error

[image]

So what's likely happening here?

Comment: I've seen this a few times too. Invalidate caches and restart or recreate a fresh venv makes it go away. PyCharm bug, I think?

Comment: @wim Looks like an interaction between `ij` and `brew` installed version of python : see my self-answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be due to assumptions by `Intellij` about the `pip` [/`pip3`] binary:

I got an error message on a *different* python package saying that `/usr/local/pip` could not be run - requires `root`.  This means the incorrect `pip` is being attempted.

I created a symbolic link to override `pip` with the `brew` version of `pip3`:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2//bin/pip3 ~/bin/pip
```

Note that the `/bin` dir is in the front of my `$PATH` so it will be seen first.

After this Intellij went about *Updating indexes* and it now "knows" about both of those packages:

[image]

**Follow-up**  The answer is not as simple as this.  I tried the same approach for additional packages e.g  `pandasql` and `fluentpy` and they gave "Installed succesfully" but the red error markers remained.

But then after installing yet *additional* packages (*pyspark* happened to be..)  *_all_* of the unresolved libraries got cleaned up.

There appears to be some unreliable application of the internal linkages. Sometimes they work sometimes not.  It appears that installing additional (possibly unrelated) packages gives Intelij an opportunity to "try again" to get it right.

Comment: PyCharm has it's own bundled pip (10.0) and it uses it when you create, for example, virtualenv. As the first thing to try you could invalidate caches under File | Invalidate Caches/Restart... which forces PyCharm to re-index your interpreter. If it doesn't help, then checking idea.log from Help | Show Log in... for relevant error messages is adviced.

Comment: Ah ok - I did not know about bundled `pip` . Will try that out.